# Why does mobile Safari cut off the text in an input form?

Tags: css, forms, web, width, mobile-safari

Why does an input form on mobile Safari have more padding inside it and push the text to the right so it gets cut off?

I set the width of the input field at 20px which is plenty for the desktop web but on mobile it needs >26px.

[image: Web Input Form]

^ Desktop Safari Web Input Form ^

[image: iOS Input Form]]

^ Mobile iOS Safari Input Form ^

**CSS**

```
.phone-input {
    width: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px !important;
    height: 1.75em;
    //border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    background: transparent;
}
```

**HTML**

```
'<div class="phone-field">'+
     '(<input class="phone-input" name="phone-input" type="tel" size="1" maxlength="1" placeholder="-" autofocus="autofocus"><input class="phone-input" name="phone-input" type="tel" size="1" maxlength="1" placeholder="-"><input class="phone-input" name="phone-input" type="tel" size="1" maxlength="1" placeholder="-">)   '+
     '<input class="phone-input" name="phone-input" type="tel" size="1" maxlength="1" placeholder="-"><input class="phone-input" name="phone-input" type="tel" size="1" maxlength="1" placeholder="-"><input class="phone-input" name="phone-input" type="tel" size="1" maxlength="1" placeholder="-"> - '+
     '<input class="phone-input" name="phone-input" type="tel" size="1" maxlength="1" placeholder="-"><input class="phone-input" name="phone-input" type="tel" size="1" maxlength="1" placeholder="-"><input class="phone-input" name="phone-input" type="tel" size="1" maxlength="1" placeholder="-"><input class="phone-input" name="phone-input" type="tel" size="1" maxlength="1" placeholder="-">'+
'<\/div>'
```

Comment: you tried with this `-webkit-appearance: none;` https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/appearance/

Comment: Is anyone has solution for this Query, the same issue I'm facing right now.

Answer (score 3):

It took me hours to figure out, but the solution is simple:

**Just use `padding: 0;`**

(Mobile safari adds a default padding to input fields)